# Cannot load image in viewcell xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This is my xaml binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:dataTemplateSelector="clr-namespace:VaultixForm;assembly=VaultixForm"
         x:Class="VaultixForm.CustomCells.OutgoingViewCell">

<Grid ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.Row="0" OutlineColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F5F5F5">
        <Image Aspect="AspectFill" x:Name="ImageView" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>

        <Label x:Name="TextView" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </Frame>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Micro" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  Text="{Binding MessagDateTime, StringFormat='{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}'}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>

</Grid>
```

My ViewModel:

```
 private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string imageurl;

    public string ImageURL
    {
        get { return imageurl; }
        set { imageurl = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private DateTime messageDateTime;

    public DateTime MessagDateTime
    {
        get { return messageDateTime; }
        set { messageDateTime = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private bool isIncoming;

    public bool IsIncoming
    {
        get { return isIncoming; }
        set { isIncoming = value;  RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }

    public bool HasAttachement => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachementUrl);

    private string attachementUrl;

    public string AttachementUrl    
    {
        get { return attachementUrl; }
        set { attachementUrl = value; RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }


}
```

}

Adding of data goes like this

```
Messages.Add(new MessageViewModel { ImageURL = "https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg", IsIncoming = false, MessagDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-25) });
```

I tried to encode the URL and even use local images. The image just does not show in the ViewCell list. There is not even an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: everything else except image loading correctly?

Comment: need xaml of your page where list with viewcell defined and code how you set bindings on your page

Comment: any Errors in the `Output` window of VisualStudio when building/launching ? i.e any BindingErrors shown there ?

Comment: Everything is working except for image.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to `ImageUrl`, but your property is named `ImageURL`. Keep in mind that WPF is (generally speaking) **case sensetive**:

> XAML is generally speaking case sensitive. For purposes of resolving backing types, WPF XAML is case sensitive by the same rules that the CLR is case sensitive. Object elements, **property elements**, and attribute names **must all be specified by using the sensitive casing when compared by name to the underlying type in the assembly, or to a member of a type**. XAML language keywords and primitives are also case sensitive. Values are not always case sensitive. Case sensitivity for values will depend on the type converter behavior associated with the property that takes the value, or the property value type. For example, properties that take the Boolean type can take either true or True as equivalent values, but only because the native WPF XAML parser type conversion for string to Boolean already permits these as equivalents.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-overview-wpf#case_and_whitespace_in_xaml

Comment: Noted. Was a typo on my end. Image still does not load though.

Comment: @nnn Are you sure it works like this (just refering to an URL from the internet)? I I think you might need to download the image first and then bind to path of the image on your device.

Comment: @DennisSchröer this should work, as stated [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/)

Comment: I did try with another URL and it works. 
URL: http://lorempixel.com/200/200/

But anything with an extension such as jpg or png does not. How do you download the image in cache and show them to the user?